# Peer-to-peer recognition system using User Points and Rules modules

Tags: 6, rules, userpoints

I would like to build a recognition system in the team where peers can recognize the effort of each other. I'm using [User Points module](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints).

**For example:**

1. UserA recognize the testing effort done by UserB.
2. UserA login to the recognition system and add 1 point to UserB in "Tester" category.
3. UserA get 1 point in "Supporter" category since he's recognizing others' effort.

**The problem:**

1. How to limit the points to be only +1; not more, not less, negative values shouldn't be allowed, more than 1 is not allowed.
2. How to automatically add +1 point to UserA who add point to UserB. I tried using [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) but it always refers to the UserB.

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem #2:

> How to automatically add +1 point to UserA who add point to UserB

In the rule Do section:

1. First, add action "Load current user account" and set User Id: [:global:user-id]. Name it as "Current user".
2. Then, in the "Grant points to a user", refer to "Current User" as User argument